# python balance bracket explanation

Tags: python

```
def balanced_brackets(s):

    stack = []
    brackets = {'(':')','[':']','{':'}'}

    for char in s:

        if char in brackets.keys():
            stack.append(char)
            print('length is', len(stack))
        else:                
            if len(stack) == 0 or brackets[stack.pop()] != char:                  
                return False

    print(len(stack))        
    return len(stack) == 0
```

im having trouble understanding bracket balancing.

i tried printing the length of stack in the for loop, but after it exits and i print stack length again it becomes 0.

how does it turn 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `else` statement, you call `stack.pop()`, which basically removes the last bracket you have to match from the stack.

The principle is for each character in the string:

1. If the character is a starting bracket, push it to the stack
2. If the character is not a starting bracket, pop the last pushed bracket in the stack, and check if it matches the character

   a. Return False if there are still characters to be parsed or the brackets don't match

   b. Continue with the next character if it matches
3. If you reach the end of th string and the stack is empty, all the brackets match

Answer (score 0):

Every time you enter the `else` statement event though your condition is not `True` to `return False` you are popping an element from the stack with `stack.pop()`. Consequently you reach the end of the `for` loop with an empty stack

Answer (score 0):

If the first character in **s** is not one of the three opening brackets, stack length will be 0 when entering the else block. Then,

`if len(stack) == 0 or brackets[stack.pop()] != char:

                return False`

will cause the function to exit.